# Invalid mode error on Python Subprocess chmod using shlex

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using subprocess in python to change permissions on newly created files in my current directory on linux.

When I run the following on the command line, it works as expected:

```
chmod 664 `find /path/path -type f`
```

I am trying to implement this in my python code with the following:

```
perms = "chmod 664 `find /path/path -type f`"
command = shlex.split(perms)
subprocess.call(command)
```

where command is the following:

```
['chmod', '664', '`find', '/path/path', '-type', 'f`']
```

I get the following error in my console:

```
chmod: invalid mode: `-type'
```

Is it something having to do with special characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special characters ``` `` ``` have to be interpreted by a shell !

You must use :

```
perms = "chmod 664 `find /path/path -type f`"
subprocess.call(perms, shell=True)
```

Alternatively, you should first execute `find /path/path -type f` and use it output to build the command

```
names = subprocess.check_output("find /path/path -type f")
command = shlex.split('chmod 664 ' + names)
subprocess.call(command)
```